# TextField como buscador

Tags: flutter

Tengo un TextField que estoy usando como buscador. Quisiera saber si se puede hacer que al momento de hacer tap en el TF se cambie el fondo y muestre una lista de elementos que estoy buscando. Si no me explico bien, seria algo asi, que pase de la imagen 1 a la imagen 2.

[image: Imagen 1í]

[image: Imagen 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer de una forma muy sencilla con el `FocusNode`, el focusNode va asignado al `TextField` si lo escuchas, puedes saber cuando se hizo foco sobre el `TextField` o también cuando se perdió el foco.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```dart
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  final _focusInput = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusInput.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusInput.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              // This is your Map
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Map here'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                child: _focusInput.hasFocus
                    ? const SearchScreen()
                    : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                focusNode: _focusInput,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Address',
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

Aquí se escucha el cambio de foco

```dart
 _focusInput.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
```

Y en la Ui se valida cuando mostrar la vista de búsqueda, usando `AnimatedSwitcher` para que tenga una transición animada.

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí te dejo más info: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus